# Using RequireJS: should I define inherited resources

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a Backbone application which uses require.js and I'm trying to work out if the resources defined lower down the chain are inherited up through the prototype chain which does appears to be the case. If this is correct what is the best practice, should I define them again or not?

My example, I have a base model which provides some custom behaviour which will be common across all my models.

```
// Base Model
define([
    'backbone'
],
function (Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    return Backbone.Model.extend({

        fetch: function (options) {
            options = options ? options : {};
            options.data = options.data ? options.data : {};
            options.data.nocache = $.now();
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    });
});
```

Then I have other models which extend the base model to inherit these common functions.

```
// Some other model
define([
    'app',
    'backbone',
    'models/base/model'
], 
function(App, Backbone, BaseModel) {
    'use strict';

    return BaseModel.extend({

        url : function() {
            return 'some/url/;
        }   
    });
});
```

As you can see I've defined `backbone` as a resource in both models but since the other models inherit from the base model.  Do I really need to define backbone here?

I'm looking for best practice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always define everything required for a module to run. If you don't, it's not really portable. If you, in the future, remove an upstream dependency, your downstream model can also break. ie,

```
define('a', ['app','backbone','myplugin', ...]
define('b', ['app','backbone','a', ...]
```

If `b` and `a` both use `myplugin`, then at some point in the future `a` no longer needs it, when you remove `myplugin` from `a` you will break `b` without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have a bunch of `some-other-models`, I would recommend putting them to shim of your require.js config file like that:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'backbone': 'path/to/backbone'
  },

  shim: {
    'models/*': { deps: [ 'backbone' ] }
  }
});
```

And then you will be able to declare deps for your `some-other-model` knowing that `backbone` is there already:

```
define(['app', 'models/base/model'], function (App, BaseModel) {
  // backbone is already loaded here
});
```

Comment: So it's possible to wildcard entire directories.  Would it work with multi-level directory structures e.g. 'models/*/*' ?

Comment: Should be tested to tell for sure. Had it tested on one of my projects and since it worked I immediately posted it :) I feel like it should work, though.